# how to identify whether the textbox value is change or not?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-change

I have  mentioned my HTML.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <input type=text ng-model="name">
</div>
```

in my JS file

```
function myCtrl($scope){
     $scope.name=//this field comes from DB say 'ABC'
}
```

My question :

When my html is get loaded, it will disply "ABC" in textbox. Which is fine. 
Now if user change that name to "XYZ", So $scope.name value is "XYZ". 
So I need to identify that input value is changed. Previous value is "ABC" and now the value is "XYZ" how we can figured it out that value is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ngChange directive.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="change()">
```

Then, in your controller, add a method called *change* to the scope:

```
$scope.change = function () {
    console.debug('Changed to ' + $scope.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue){

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myCtrl($scope){
    var dbName= 'ABC'; //this field comes from DB say 'ABC'
    $scope.name= dbName;
    $scope.$watch('name', function(newValue) {
       if(newValue != dbName) {
           // do something
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't need to indicate last parameter `true` in watch expression, it means to watch for changes of object properties. `name` field you are watching is string